# What is the right way of killing a task that works with a file Stream

Tags: c#, file-io, task, cancellation

I have a parrallel task that writes some data in a file

```
using (var lFileStream = File.Open(aDestinationFile, shouldResume ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    try
    {
        while ((lCount = lDownloadStream.Read(lBuf, 0, lBuf.Length)) > 0)
        {
            lFileStream.Write(lBuf, 0, lCount);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        lFileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

I am launching the task by:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        myMethod();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Exc(ex);
                    }
                }
            , _resetEvent.Token);
```

under some condition I have to terminate the task:

```
_resetEvent.Cancel(false);
try
{
    _task.Dispose();
}
catch
{
}
```

after the task stop I am starting a new task, but when i am try to aceess the file that was used i am getting:

> The process cannot access the file 'bla-bla' because it is being used
>   by another process.

how can I "kill" the task properly?

Comment: You don't need your try-finaly block the `Dispose()` called from your `using` block calls `Close()` for you.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain To correct what you said: `using` won't call `Close` it will call `Dispose` which in turn calls `Close`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That's what I was trying to say (Thanks for making it less convoluted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass a `CancellationToken` in to a task all that does is prevent the task from starting if the token is canceled by the time the task scheduler gets around to starting the task. It has no effect on the task once the task has already started up.

What you need to do is "Cooperative Cancelation", you need to check the token inside your code that is running inside the task and have it cancel what it is doing. The easiest way to do that is just pass the CancelationToken in to the method itself then run the function `ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` and your program will throw a `OperationCanceledException` and do whatever cleanup you have set up to handle that exception.

```
private void myMethod(CancellationToken token)
{
    using (var lFileStream = File.Open(aDestinationFile, shouldResume ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        //The try-finally was not nessessary, Dispose() will call Close() for you.
        while ((lCount = lDownloadStream.Read(lBuf, 0, lBuf.Length)) > 0)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            lFileStream.Write(lBuf, 0, lCount);
        }
    }
}

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        myMethod(_resetEvent.Token);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //If the task was canceled we don't need to log the exception.
                        if(!ex is OperationCanceledException)
                            Log.Exc(ex);
                    }
                }
            , _resetEvent.Token);
```

---

To reduce refactoring you could do the following to your writer method

```
//All your old code can still call this method.
public void myMethod()
{
    myMethod(CancellationToken.None); //Call the overload with a empty token.
}

//New code that needs to cancel the operation can call this method.
public void myMethod(CancellationToken token)
{
     //Slightly modified old Writer code that uses the CancelationToken inside any loops or in between any long running operations that can't be interrupted.
}
```

Comment: did I get it right the "cooperative cancalation" is the only way to do it? I am asking the question, because the "writer" method is the code that is also used by other methods in my solution. that why I'd like to to avoid refactoring

Comment: Yes, the writer method must "cooperate" with the cancelation or else you must wait for the write to finish before it will be "closed" by the system. See my update to make the refactoring easier on you, you only need to modify the writer function and any functions you want to support canceling the operation, all the other uses of the writer function can be left unchanged.

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Factory.StartNew`. You want to use `Stream.BeginWrite` and `Stream.EndWrite` along with `TaskFactory.FromAsync`.

Comment: To make it even more responsive if you are using .NET 4.5 or [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) in .NET 4.0 you can make your code use async/await and replace the `void Stream.Write(byte[], int, int)` calls to `Task Stream.WriteAsync(byte[], int, int, CancelationToken)` and pass in the token to the write function. This will make your function stop as soon as the token is raised instead of waiting for `Write(` to return.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain `Stream.WriteAsync` is 4.5 and not 4.0

Comment: @Aron I used it because I assumed he is using .NET 4.0 which does not have those features, however my last comment addresses that. And the library `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` adds the extension method `public static Task WriteAsync(this Stream source, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`